# Percentage regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

Just a quick one here, does anyone know of a good regular expression for a percentage? Including 2 decimal places, i.e. 15.22%. I'm looking to put it inside a regularexpressionvalidator in ASP.NET.

Comment: Can you add further infomation. How will a percentage be added in you application. Is there a limit to the percentage. i.e. Can it only go up to 100%. Dont you just need a numeric regex with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Regarding all the answers here: Note that in .NET without specifying the EcmaScript regex option, `\d` matches any unicode digit, not only 0-9! For instance those: ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩

Comment: How about _there was a 150% growth last year_ - does it have to be <= 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This accepts 0.00%-100.00% including any number of leading zeros:

```
^0*(100\.00|[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})%$
```

Comment: How would you expand on this regex to make the percentage sign at the end optional? My web form should allow users to add both 12.5% and 12.5 as legal values. I can remove the percentage symbol in codebehind after.

Comment: @Johncl, just add a ? after the %: `^0*(100\.00|[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})%?$` - and if the comma and part after the comma is to be optional then use this: `^0*(100(\.00?)?|[0-9]?[0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)%?$`

Comment: this one should handle '0' and '100'
^0*(100\.00|0|100|[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})%?$

Answer (score 3):

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?%)
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to reflect @Lucero's input:

Forcing 2 decimals

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}%$
```

Allowing either 2 decimals (with decimal) or integer. Both followed by percent.

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?%$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d\d\.\d\d%
```

To make the decimal portion optional:

```
\d\d(\.\d\d)?%
```

If single digit values are not padded with zeros:

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d\d)?%
```

Finally, to allow 100%

```
(100|\d{1,2}(\.\d\d)?)%
```