# Is it possible to write a regular expression to check this:

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression to check whether all numbers of specific `10` digit number occured up to 3 times?
for example return value for `Regex.IsMatch("xxxx", "4433425425")` is false. 
and for `Regex.IsMatch("xxxx", "4463322545")` is true. what is xxxx?
in the first one i have `4 occurrence` of digit `4` and in second one non of digits occurred more than `3` times.

Comment: @Saeed, occurred three times in a row, or three times at all?

Comment: The question is not really clear to me. Do you mean all digits appears 3 times or more in a 10 digits number ?

Comment: I've edited the question if its not clear yet i don't know how to clear it.

Comment: Based on the examples you provided for what should match and what shouldn't match, you are still not clearing stating your question.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @SaeedAlg: the question is **still** unclear to me. When you write all *numbers* do you mean all *digits* ? (ie: 43 is a number, 434343 is a number reapeated 3 times). Does 'up to 3 times' means that the first example does not match because 3, 2, or 5 are repeated only 2 times, or because 4 is repeated 4 times ? Seems to be the second one looking at the accepted answer and the second exemple (other wording could be *at least one digit is repeated 4 times*), but right now the question is still unclear.

Comment: yes all digits is true, i think up to means !(at least) may be I'm wrong, at all I've provided the examples to show what i want. the situation you think is more complicated :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will match any digit that has four or more instances

```
 string found =  Regex.Match(s,@"(\d).*\1.*\1.*\1").Groups[1].Value;
```

Just an example of how to use it

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
     string fail = "1234567890";
     string s = "1231231222";
     string mTxt = @"(\d).*\1.*\1.*\1";
     Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match(s,mTxt).Success);
     Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(fail, mTxt).Success);
}
```

---

Baised on @Brads Comments below use

```
([0-9]).*\1.*\1.*\1
```

Comment: +1 for using backreferences. I incorporated your answer into mine (and attributed you credit)

Comment: @Brad - kinda funny. "Nice answer. Maybe I can get some rep for it too."

Comment: It's just checking that at least **one** digit is repeated four times. Was it really the question ?

Comment: He wanted to see that no character had at most three occurences the same as if any character has four

Answer (score 3):

Find a number occurring three times in a row:

`(?=(0{3}|1{3}|2{3}|3{3}|4{3}|5{3}|6{3}|7{3}|8{3}|9{3}).{3}`

Find a number occurring three times anywhere in the string:

`(.?0.?){3}|(.?1.?){3}|(.?2.?){3}|(.?3.?){3}|(.?4.?){3}|(.?5.?){3}|(.?6.?){3}|(.?7.?){3}|(.?8.?){3}|(.?9.?){3}`

Using backreferences (C/O @rerun):

`([0-9]).*\1.*\1.*`

**NOTE:** this will check the entire string for multiple characters. There is no limitation to the first 10 characters in the string. Let me know if you need that.

Comment: @Brad, thanks, I can't understand it but i test it with "2262345354" and i got false answer it should be true.

Comment: I always see the [0-9] groping notation instead of the \d is there a reason aren't they the same.

Comment: @rerun, `\d` can match any unicode digit, not only 0-9. See comment by Lucero on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959810/percentage-regex

Comment: good to know.  I've used \d since I was coding perl 10 years ago

Comment: @Saeed, I shouldn't have been using the zero-width look-ahead. I've corrected it, but I still say that @rerun's use of backreferences is superior if your engine understands it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to risk downvotes here and suggest that regexes are most likely not the best tool for this job.

They have their place but I usually find that, if you're getting into "horrendous" territory with multiple backtracking or negative lookahead and lots of `or` clauses, you're probably better off tossing away the whole regex idea and writing a simple string scanning function which simply count each digit and ensures the counts are correct at the end. Pseudo-code something like:

```
def isValid (str):
    foreach ch in '0'..'9':
        count[ch] = 0
    foreach ch in str:
        if ch not in '0'..'9':
            return false
        count[ch] = count[ch] + 1
    foreach ch in '0'..'9':
        if count[ch] > 3:
            return false
    return true
```

That's my advice, take it or leave it, I won't be offended :-)

Comment: @SaeedAlg, it _is_ a good challenge. Unfortunately it's 11pm Fri night and I need to watch Big Bang Theory then get some sleep for the kids' sports stuff tomorrow. So I'll have to stick with the answer I gave :-) I'll keep an eye on this though since I'm interested (mostly in the readability of solutions).